# Taskbar is very weird

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

My taskbar is very weird, sometimes the right-side icons including the clock disappear:
[image]
Other times it looks even more weird:
[image]

And when I hover mouse over that big mess at right, it gets better

What should it be?
I even reinstalled windows 10...

#### Update

Just found another thing about this bug.
When I change color in appearance it blinks..

[image]

Sorry for the stretched out gif, I wasn't able to show in another way

And another thing I found out, is when I click in the bottom right corner, sometimes it doesn't send me to desktop.

#### Update

I don't know if this is an important thing but if I reboot in safe mode is the same

### Another Update

[image]

If i set to autohide taskbar, it's fine, but as I change not to hide, there in right are some messy icons, and if I hover mouse there they fix

Comment: Could be a problem with the graphics driver. What make and exact model is your GPU?

Comment: I agree about the graphics card / driver. This is not normal for Windows 10.

Comment: My GPU is a Nvidia MX350

Comment: Okay, so it’s a rather up-to-date GPU. Have you tried updating the graphics driver yet?

Comment: They are already updated, at least the nvidia. About the Intel ones, I'm not sure how to update the, but in Windows Update, it's all updated

Answer (score 0):

So, I had discovered what was causing this problem, it's Fences that with a the update KB5003214 was causing that.
You may see this: https://forums.stardock.com/505331/windows-update-kb5003214-issues

I didn't have that update installed, so I searched deeper and figured out another related updates: KB5004476, KB5003637 and 21H1, I uninstalled these 3 updates and now it's fine.